# How to create dashed uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uibutton, storyboard

In my project I want create dashed uibutton like shown in this pricture. Is there a way I to change dashed color as well?

Comment: the easiest solution might be to create an image - with the words and whatever colour dashed line you want, and just set that as the UIButton.image.  If you need it to be dynamic, you can programatically create the image, and set it at run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments and answers suggest, you *could* use an image, but we can use a `CAShapeLayer` instead and have control on every aspect.

Something like this perhaps:

```
class DashedButton: UIButton {

    var dashedLine: CAShapeLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        dashedLine             = CAShapeLayer()
        dashedLine.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        dashedLine.lineWidth   = 4
        layer.addSublayer(dashedLine)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        dashedLine.lineDashPattern = [12, 7]
        dashedLine.path = path.cgPath
    }

}
```

which can be used like (note that I am using the frame here cause I tested it in a playground, a more common use would be the instantiation via a storyboard/xib file):

```
let button = DashedButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))

button.setTitle("Forgot Password?", for: .normal)
button.dashedLine.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
button.sizeToFit()
```

which produces this:

[image]

---

**Sidenote**: This example is a quick way to get you started. You could add custom setters for example to handle line coloring and patterns. Also note that I have "cheated" in a way by specifying a pattern that fills the entire width of a button ending with a dash instead of a gap, and not dynamically calculating lengths (left as an exercise for anyone that is interested in this solution :))